# multi redux store on node socket server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, server-side, multistore

I'm currently learning react and redux and I am making a practical project in order to be face of some issues.

The project is a multiplayer labyrinth so I decided that using a socket.io server and also that player will be limited in a labyrinth game context, so I am using room (io namespace).

All the game context is store in redux on the node server and is connect to the clients UI.

because of that I have multi-Rooms server I want a different store for each room/game. In absolute I can combine reducers but that mean lot of performance lost and need a dark architecture of action and store.

the problem is that I don't know how create multi-store on node.js

currently the server work in this case ->
on client connect ->  if the current room is full generate a new game else assign on current room

```
  public generate = (server:SocketIO.Server) =>{
        let newIDGenetator = new Idgenerator();
        let store = redux.createStore(labActionReducer);
        let room = server.of('/room'+this.labs.length);
        let socketHandler =  new SocketHandler(room,store,newIDGenetator);
        this.labs.push(socketHandler);

this is the function call for generate a new game:
-> create idgenerator which is just an incr who's return is value cast in string 
-> create a new store 
-> create a io namespace 
-> create a new socketHandler which implements:

    
room.on('connect' , (client,store) => 
    client.on('foo',()=> 
         store.dispatch({type:bar});
    )
)
```

and listen store in order to send the new state to each clients of the handling room

the first room work well but when a second root is create the client show the data of the first room state when I attempt to get the initial state

The client is connect on the good namespace,

So I suppose that createStore do not create a new store. Could you help me to create a new store independent of the first? if need more details I can give you the GitHub link of the project.

thank you for reading

edit: socketHandler code:

```
export class SocketHandler{
    private playersId = {};
    private store:Store<Lab,LabActionTypes>;
    constructor(server:Namespace,store:Store<Lab,LabActionTypes>,idgenerator:Idgenerator){
        this.store = store;

        store.subscribe(()=>{
            console.log(this.store.getState());
            for(let playerId in this.playersId){
                let newState = this.store.getState() //utiliser reducer_relatif(state,playerId)
                this.playersId[playerId].emit('gridChanged',newState);
             }
        })

        server.on('connect',(client)=>{
            let newID = idgenerator.generetaId()
            this.playersId[newID]=client;
            store.dispatch(action.NewPlayer(newID));
            NewClient(client,store,this);
        });

    }
    public getPlayerBySocket = (socket:SocketIO.Socket)=>{
        for(let playerId in this.playersId){
            if(this.playersId[playerId]===socket){
                return playerId;
            }
        }
    }
}

export const NewClient = (client: SocketIO.Socket,store:redux.Store<Lab,LabActionTypes>,socketHandler:SocketHandler) => {                 


    client.on('up',()=>{
        let player = socketHandler.getPlayerBySocket(client);
        store.dispatch(action.PlayerMooveUp(player,store));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
    })
    
    client.on('down',()=>{
        let player = socketHandler.getPlayerBySocket(client);
        store.dispatch(action.PlayerMooveDown(player,store));
    })
        
    client.on('left',()=>{
        let player = socketHandler.getPlayerBySocket(client);
        store.dispatch(action.PlayerMooveLeft(player,store));
    })

    client.on('right',()=>{
        let player = socketHandler.getPlayerBySocket(client);
        store.dispatch(action.PlayerMooveRight(player,store));
    })
```

Comment: Why use redux at all? Wouldn't a simple object work? You already have event handlers for the socket events.

Comment: because the goal of this is learning Redux our more use the Redux "philosophy" for creating a app meaning functional programming instead of object programming and circular data flow. This exercise let me compare functional and object programming

Comment: As your project is already heavily event based, I would caution that redux may not be a good fit in this scenario. Check out this article from the creator of redux to learn more: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367